# How do you move windows around in Xming (or generally in X-Windows)?

Tags: x-windows, xming

I'm using Molden, a molecular modeling program in the Xming X-Windows server, and when I set it up to put it's myriad subwindows into a single frame, I seem to lose the ability to move them around and bring them forward (on top of other windows).

In the below picture the "Directory..." window should be above the window with more buttons, as I'm trying to open a file.

[image]

How do I do this in Xming, or assuming this is like X-Windows anywhere, in X-Windows.

Comment: Was Xming started with the [-multiwindow](http://www.straightrunning.com/XmingNotes/manual.php) option?

Answer (score 1):

Your X session isn't running a window manager of any kind. Ask the administrator of the remote system what window managers are available (icewm, fvwm, etc.). Then, if you're running molden from an xterm or similar prompt, you can run the window manager first, then run molden. Something like:

```
$ fvwm & # Run window manager in background
$ molden
```

Comment: I'm actually running the program and X-windows server all locally

Comment: You still need a window manager (don't know what you'd use on Windows), or to let it run in multiple windows (i.e., not all in one X frame).

Comment: @MikeRenfro When you run xming, the Windows desktop serves as your window manager. Try to run a window manager on the remote system and it will complain that there's already one running.

Answer (score 0):

If it's stuck in the corner or something you can get at its MS windows system menu through the task manager, select move on that then (critically) start with one press of a cursor key then use the mouse.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).